# How to mapping one relation trough another relation in Doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have three entities `Stock`, `StockDetail` and `CatalogHasStock`. In `CatalogHasStock` this is the mapping I have:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="StockBundle\Entity\StockDetail")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns(@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product", referencedColumnName="product"),
 *                  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company", referencedColumnName="company"),
 *                  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="stock_detail", referencedColumnName="id"),
 *                  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="upc", referencedColumnName="upc"),
 *                  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="kcondition", referencedColumnName="kcondition"))
 */
protected $stock;
```

Now in `StockDetail` this is the mapping:

```
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="StockBundle\Entity\Stock", inversedBy="sdetails")
   * @ORM\JoinColumns(@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product", referencedColumnName="product"),
   *                  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company", referencedColumnName="company"),
   *                  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="kcondition", referencedColumnName="kcondition"))
   */
  protected $stock;
```

I need to insert values in `CatalogHasStock` and I doing in this way:

```
$catalog_has_stock = new CatalogHasStock ();
$catalog_has_stock->setStock($entityStockDetail);
```

But I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: product in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php
>   line 685

What is wrong in the mapping part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this syntax:

```
* @ORM\JoinColumns({
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product", referencedColumnName="product"),
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company", referencedColumnName="company"),
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="kcondition", referencedColumnName="kcondition")
* })
```

etc.
It seems like you forgot `{}`